# WSO2 identity server bridge with zimbra

Tags: ldap, wso2, single-sign-on, saml, zimbra

Would someone be so kind and explain me how to deploy zimbra collaboration suite into wso2 identity server? I know how to make zimbra to use external ldap server, but i do not know exactly how to make a saml sso bridge between them and put the zimbra into the Authorized Apps tab.I am looking forward to hearing from you.Thank you in advance!

Edit:

Since i haven't found any solution to integrate zimbra with saml sso, i used their SSO Preauth way, more info at http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Preauth